# How to publish Chisel package?

Tags: scala, sbt, chisel

I made some chisel [projects](https://github.com/Martoni/fpgamacro) [published](https://github.com/Martoni/GbHdmi) on [my github repositories](https://github.com/Martoni?tab=repositories).
All projects are initialized with chisel-template official example.

For the moment to use [these as packages I have to «publish it local»](https://github.com/Martoni/HdmiCore#install). But I want to publish it «officially» on the web to avoid cloning the github project.

Is there a tutorial that explain how to publish chisel-template projects as official package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with github publish system following [Manuel Rodriguez tutorial](https://medium.com/@supermanue/how-to-publish-a-scala-library-in-github-bfb0fa39c1e4).

In short :

- Make a github token on your github account
- set shell environment GITHUB_TOKEN with the token :

```bash
export GITHUB_TOKEN=gxb_xxxTENRSTyourToken
```

- Add following lines in your `build.sbt`:

```scala
//...
githubOwner := "GITHUB_USERNAME"
githubRepository := "GITHUB_PROJECT"
//...
```

- Add following line in your `project/plugin.sbt` file (create directory and file if not exists):

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.codecommit" % "sbt-github-packages" % "0.5.3")
```

- Launch sbt then publish :

```scala
$ sbt
sbt:project> publish
```

Your project is published. I done it for chisel project [fpgamacro](https://github.com/Martoni/fpgamacro) as an example.

To use fpgamacro on another project I added this lines to [build.sbt](https://github.com/Martoni/chisNesPad/blob/master/build.sbt) project :

```scala
...
    externalResolvers += "fpgamacro packages" at "https://maven.pkg.github.com/Martoni/fpgamacro",
...
      "Martoni" %% "fpgamacro" % "0.2.0",
```

I'm using fpgamacro in [chisNesPad](https://github.com/Martoni/chisNesPad) project for example.